# Appending to list of lists

Tags: python, list

I'm a real newbie with Python and struggling with the lack of arrays. I could use numpy of course but it feels like a cop out for someone trying to learn. So with that said why can't I use append with a list of lists? Here is my code

```
myList = ['Tom','Colin']

# so now my list is ['Tom', 'Colin']
myList.append('Tom')

# Append works so now my list is ['Tom', 'Colin', 'Tom'] Yes I did mean to have two Tom entries

myListOfLists=['Tom', '24'],['Colin', '25']
row =  ['Tom', '31']

myListOfLists.append(row)
# this gives the dreaded AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'append' error
```

I don't understand why I can't append to a list of lists

Comment: Because you have a tuple of lists.  You're missing the outer brackets: `[['Tom', '24'],['Colin', '25']]`

Comment: And tuples are immutable and cannot be appended to.

Comment: I mean, it says right there: `AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'append'`. This is telling you that the thing, `myListOfLists`, that you're trying to `append` to, is a `tuple` rather than the `list` you expect.

Answer (score 2):

`myListOfLists` is not a list of lists. It is a tuple of lists.

Replace

```
myListOfLists=['Tom', '24'],['Colin', '25']
```

With

```
myListOfLists=[['Tom', '24'],['Colin', '25']]
```

`tuple` do not have any `append` method, but `list` have.

```
myListOfLists=['Tom', '24'],['Colin', '25']
print(type(myListOfLists))
# <class 'tuple'>
print(hasattr(myListOfLists, 'append'))
# False

myListOfLists=[['Tom', '24'],['Colin', '25']]
print(type(myListOfLists))
# <class 'list'>
print(hasattr(myListOfLists, 'append'))
# True
```

Answer (score 1):

When you write

```
myListOfLists=['Tom', '24'],['Colin', '25']
```

you do not create a list of list, but a pair (tuple of 2 elements) containing two lists of two elements each.

A tuple cannot be modified (we say they are immutable), that's why calling `append` on a tuple raises an error.

If you want a list of list, you want to write

```
myListOfLists=[['Tom', '24'],['Colin', '25']]
```

and your code will work.

Answer (score 1):

you can't use `list.append` because `myListOfLists` is a `tuple`

---

you can have a new list where you unpack the previous values of `myListOfLists` and include also your `row`:

```
myListOfLists=['Tom', '24'],['Colin', '25']
row =  ['Tom', '31']

myListOfLists = [*myListOfLists, row]

# [['Tom', '24'], ['Colin', '25'], ['Tom', '31']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to encase `myListOfLists` in brackets `[]`:

```
myListofLists = [['Tom', '24'],['Colin', '25']]
myListofLists.append(['Tom', '31'])
print(myListofLists)
# returns [['Tom', '24'], ['Colin', '25'], ['Tom', '31']]
```

See, so now you have a list of lists!